# 2 backgrounds, 1 in top and 1 in screen or page footer

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make my site with 2 backgrounds, 
first background in top and second one in footer, currently im using the below code:

```
body { 
background: url(images/bgfooter.png) bottom center repeat-x, url(images/bgheader.png) top center repeat-x;
}
```

this css is working well when page is bigger than screen height, but i have some of pages with about height 500px and in these cases bgfooter isn't showing in footer,

i like to add something like this,

```
body { 
background: url(images/bgfooter.png) bottom center repeat-x, url(images/bgheader.png) top center repeat-x;
min-width: screensize;
}
```

any option?

Comment: This seems incredibly hacky. Why don't you just divide your site into content and footer with separate divs, and add a background to each separately?

Comment: tried but after making footer position absolute, some content of page is hided

Comment: Well that means you're doing something wrong. ;) Try showing what code you've tried for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the background img to the body and then set a separate background img for the footer.

```
body { 
background: url(images/bgheader.png) top center repeat-x;
}

#footer {
background: url(images/bgfooter.png) bottom center repeat-x;
}
```

Your HTML

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="footer">
</div> <!-- END OF FOOTER DIV -->

</body>
</html>
```

Now that you have set the background img to footer you may adjust any other attributes to the footer and body to your preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can set a dubble background in CSS3

```
background: 
url(number.png) 600px 10px no-repeat,  /* On top,    like z-index: 4; */
url(thingy.png) 10px 10px no-repeat,   /*            like z-index: 3; */
url(Paper-4.png);                      /* On bottom, like z-index: 1; */
```